# Get pagesource of opened Chrome tab

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to find a way to get the page-source from an opened Chrome tab.

Be careful, I cannot use the Webbrowser-component because I get an error message that the browser is outdated. Even when I try to use the webclient it doesn't work because I get the same error.

So I really need to use the opened Chrome tab window.

I can open the page without any problem and I can get the windowhandle too but I don't know how to get to the page source.
The page is a proprietary systems status result page, so I cannot modify anything in it and it's only available inside a local network, so it's not online.

Anybody has an idea?

```
public Process proc = null;

private void openWebpage()
{
   proc = Process.Start("chrome.exe", baseUrl);
}

private void getPageSource()
{
   IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
   foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
   {
       if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Status Report"))
       {

       }

   }
}
```